# Match the atlassian wiki markup for "a" link in a given string of text

Tags: c#, regex

I need help creating a c# regex pattern that will look up an "a" link markup from a string.

Here is a sample input text:
`string text = "some line of text with random [ in the line. [http://example.com] [link title|http://example.com]";`

I can't get it to match on the `[http://example.com]` or `[link title|http://example.com]`

I tried many failed patterns, here are just the last 2:

```
@"\[(?<innerHtml>[.^\]]+)\|(?<href>[.^\]]+)\]\s"
@"\[(?<innerHtml>[^[]+.+)\]"
```

most of them return a match as shown from the "string text".

```
in the line. [http://example.com] [link title|http://example.com
```

Specs:

- This is a single line of text with no \n\r possible.
- The first [ can be at the start of the line and a line can end with ].
- If 2 link markups are present in the text they will always have a space between them "...] [...".

| Markup | Replace |
| --- | --- |
| `[href]` | `@"<a href=""${href}"">${href}</a>"` |
| `[innerHtml|href]` | `@"<a href=""${href}"">${innerHtml}</a>"` |

Comment: I think you're trying to do: `\[(?:(?<innerHtml>[^[|\]]+)\|)?(?<href>[^[\]]+)\]`. Here's a [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cinnerHtml%3e%5b%5e%5b%7c%5c%5d%5d%2b%29%5c%7c%29%3f%28%3f%3chref%3e%5b%5e%5b%5c%5d%5d%2b%29%5c%5d&i=some+line+of+text+with+random+%5b+in+the+line.+%5bhttp%3a%2f%2fexample.com%5d+%5blink+title%7chttp%3a%2f%2fexample.com%5d).

Comment: Prefect! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A couple of notes:**

- To use a negated character class, the `^` character **must** immediately follow the opening bracket (i.e., `[^...]`. Otherwise, it's treated as a literal character.
- In order to match links without titles, the first part needs to be optional.

You may use the following pattern:

```
\[(?:(?<innerHtml>[^[|\]]+)\|)?(?<href>[^[\]]+)\]
```

**[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3CinnerHtml%3E%5B%5E%5B%7C%5C%5D%5D%2B%29%5C%7C%29%3F%28%3F%3Chref%3E%5B%5E%5B%5C%5D%5D%2B%29%5C%5D&i=some%20line%20of%20text%20with%20random%20%5B%20in%20the%20line.%20%5Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%5D%20%5Blink%20title%7Chttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%5D)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `\[` - Match the `[` character literally.
- `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group.

  - `(?<innerHtml>` - Start of the first named group.

    - `[^[|\]]+` - A negated class to match one more characters other than `[`, `|`, and `]`.
  - `)` - Close the named group.
  - `\|` - match the `|` character literally.
- `)` - Close the non-capturing group.
- `?` - Indicate that the previous group is optional.
- `(?<href>[^[\]]+)` - Match one or more characters other than `[` and `]` and capture them in the second named group.
- `\]` - Match the `]` character literally.